# How to "literally" open up an excel sheet? Not looking for pd.read_excel but something that opens and displays the sheet in excel

Tags: python

I have a Python GUI where I convert a .txt file to a .xlsx file. If any values are out of norm, then the script reformats those cells by highlighting the background and then I save the .xlsx file. When completed, I want to open the .xlsx file for the actual GUI user to be able to see and correct the highlighted cells.

Something like...

> > pandas.read_excel('foo.xlsx')

but literally opens the Excel application

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
file = 'foo.xlsx'
os.startfile(file)
```

Comment: This will only work on `win32` platforms. For xnix/macos OP would need to use the `x-open` command with `popopen`

Comment: @modesitt ... or `os.system()` or `subprocess.run()` perhaps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python